How do I stop slugs and wasps in vegetables
I have slugs and wasps eating my strawberries. I have placed beer in cups and it attracts some but doesn't last long.How do I stop them?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can't buy slug bait to sprinkle, or use diatomaceous earth, or spray with dish soap?

Screen cloches for strswberries.
